# JRuby Garbage Collection throws error when running Unit and Functional tests in Rails

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, garbage-collection, jruby

I'm running into an issue with JRuby and Garbage Collection in my tests in a Rails app (3.2.8). When I run my unit tests, I'm just fine, but when I run both unit and functional or just functional, it tends to blow up with a strange stacktrace as below.

I have no idea what is going on. This only started happening when I upgraded Rails and upgraded JRuby from 1.6.3 to 1.6.7.2.

```
 /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/bin/jruby -I"lib:test" -I"/home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib" "/home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/**/*_test.rb"
   * WARNING: 'test: #channel_id should return the correct channel id. ' is already defined
 Loaded suite /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
 Started
 ...............................................................................
 ...............................................................................
 ...............................................................................
 ...............................................................................
 ...............................................................................
 ...............................................................................
 ...........................................................

 Finished in 156.993 seconds.

 533 tests, 1030 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
 0% passed

 3.40 tests/s, 6.56 assertions/s
 /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/bin/jruby -I"lib:test" -I"/home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib" "/home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/functional/**/*_test.rb"
 LoadError: No such file to load -- java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
            depend_on at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317
            depend_on at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313
   require_dependency at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225
          eager_load! at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:439
                 each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615
          eager_load! at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438
                 each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615
          eager_load! at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436
             Finisher at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53
        instance_exec at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1757
                  run at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30
     run_initializers at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55
                 each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615
     run_initializers at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54
          initialize! at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136
             __send__ at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698
                 send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097
       method_missing at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30
               (root) at /home/mbridges/admin_tools/mbridges_dev/customer_service_tool/config/environment.rb:12
              require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1042
               (root) at /home/mbridges/admin_tools/mbridges_dev/customer_service_tool/config/environment.rb:2
              require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1042
               (root) at /home/mbridges/admin_tools/mbridges_dev/customer_service_tool/test/test_helper.rb:1
              require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1042
             __file__ at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10
                 each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615
             __file__ at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9
               select at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2395
               (root) at /home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4
 rake aborted!
 Command failed with status (1): [/home/mbridges/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7...]

 Tasks: TOP => without_schema_dump:functionals
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The Rakefile is a bit different since we are not actually in control of the database. We have to skip migrations.

# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
    # for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

CustomerService::Application.load_tasks

namespace :without_schema_dump do
  Rake::TestTask.new(:units) do |t|
    t.libs << "test"
    t.pattern = 'test/unit/**/*_test.rb'
    t.verbose = true
  end
  Rake::TestTask.new(:functionals) do |t|
    t.libs << "test"
    t.pattern = 'test/functional/**/*_test.rb'
    t.verbose = true
  end
  task :run_tests => :environment do
    Rake::Task['without_schema_dump:units'].invoke
    Rake::Task['without_schema_dump:functionals'].invoke
  end
end

Rake::Task[:default].prerequisites.clear
Rake::Task[:default].actions.clear
task :default do
  puts 'WARNING: Default rake overwritten because of foreign key constraints (see Rakefile)'
  Rake::Task['without_schema_dump:run_tests'].invoke
end
```

Help? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

most likely the newer JRuby is doing some more job and is hitting the GC limit :

GC checks if not too much time is spent doing GC while reclaiming too "little" memory ...
increasing the heap size should solve this issue try: `export JRUBY_OPTS="--client -J-Xmx=640m"`

it also might be a regression "bug" but I do not think there's going to be another **1.6.x** release. there are some backports in **1.6.8** you might try if the issue persists and also if it happens with **1.7.0**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.oom